# How to properly checks socks5 proxies

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, proxy, socks, proxies

Hello today i posted some Socks5 proxies on a forum and some person went in discussion with me and said many of the proxies where "connect" proxies and socks4  proxies but i don't think my code is checking for any socks4 proxies:

```
def process(self, task):
    global alive
    global dead
    global tested
    proxy = task
    ip,port = proxy.split(":")
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout_value)
    log_msg = str("Trying Socks5 proxy%21s " % proxy)
    socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, ip, int(port))
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket

    try:
        t1 = time.time()
        response = requests.get(test_url, timeout=timeout_value)
        tested += 1
        t2 = time.time()
    except Exception as e:
        log_msg += "%s " % fail_msg
        print(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + log_msg + " " + str(tested))
        dead += 1
        tested += 1
        return None
    if "Connection working" in response.text: 
        log_msg += ok_msg + "Response time: %d" % (int((t2-t1)*1000))
        print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + log_msg)
        text_file = open(out_filename, "a")
        text_file.write(proxy + "\r\n")
        text_file.close()
        alive += 1
        return proxy
    else:
        log_msg += "%s " % fail_msg
        print(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + log_msg + " " + str(tested))
        dead += 1
        tested += 1
        return None
```

I don't know what i could be doing wrong, the person said he has been checking proxies since 2002 and he is the first person out of thousands to complain about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proxy could in theory handle socks4, socks5 and connect (i.e. HTTP proxy) at the same time and on the same port, which means both of you might be right. With all of these protocols the client sends the first message and these messages differ significantly between socks4, socks5 and connect. Thus a proxy can decide based on this first message what kind of protocol the client is asking for. And, while I'm not aware of any proxy which handles all three protocols on the same port it is at least common to handle both socks4 and socks5 at the same port by the same proxy.

Comment: that is what i was thinking